# How to create a structure instance out of a -pkg.el file?

Tags: package, cl-lib, defstruct

Package `foo` description is stored inside a file `foo-VERSION/foo-pkg.el` with a cl-defstruct definition that complies to package.el `package-desc` structure type with a `package-desc-from-define` constructor.  Something like this (for the package `ace-link`):

```lisp
(define-package
  "ace-link"
  "20210121.923"
  "Quickly follow links"
  '((avy "0.4.0"))
  :commit "e1b1c91b280d85fce2194fea861a9ae29e8b03dd"
  :authors '(("Oleh Krehel" . "ohwoeowho@gmail.com"))
  :maintainer '("Oleh Krehel" . "ohwoeowho@gmail.com")
  :keywords '("convenience" "links" "avy")
  :url "https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-link")
```

Inside package.el, the `define-package` function is not meant to be called.  I'd like to dynamically extract the information from all the `-pkg.el` files and process them further.

What is the best way to create a structure instance of that?

To circumvent the package.el definition of `define-package` I temporary re-defined `define-package` to the constructor and then applied the code once manually like this:

```lisp
(defalias 'define-package 'package-desc-from-define) 
(setq instance-value (define-package
                       "ace-link"
                       "20210121.923"
                       "Quickly follow links"
                       '((avy "0.4.0"))
                       :commit "e1b1c91b280d85fce2194fea861a9ae29e8b03dd"
                       :authors '(("Oleh Krehel" . "ohwoeowho@gmail.com"))
                       :maintainer '("Oleh Krehel" . "ohwoeowho@gmail.com")
                       :keywords '("convenience" "links" "avy")
                       :url "https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-link"))
```

That works, but its I'd like to do the same thing just using the file name: being able to create an `instance-value` but processing the content of the `-pkg.el` file.

So I wrote another alias that creates a global variable instance `my-struct-instance`:

```lisp
(defun my-def (n v &optional s r &rest pl)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         "Replaces package-desc-from-define."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
         (setq my-struct-instance (apply 'package-desc-from-define n v s r pl)))
(defalias 'define-package 'my-def)
```

Then I load the file with something like:

```lisp
(load "~/.emacs.d/elpa/ace-link-xxx/ace-link-pkg.el")
```

And that creates an instance of the structure inside the variable `my-struct-instance`.

I get the feeling it should be easy and I'm missing something in the handling of *cl-defstruct*.  Is there a better, more obvious way to extract the structure information from these `-pkg.el` files?

Comment: `(package-load-descriptor DIRECTORY)` ?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  I knew there ought to be something simpler!  I looked at its code and it essentially reads the content of the -pkg.el file in a buffer and then reads it into the argument of package-process-define-package.  That's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Cool.  I'll add it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(package-load-descriptor DIRECTORY)` will read the `*-pkg.el` file in the given directory, create a new `package-desc` structure object, add it to `package-alist` and return the object.

That seems to cover what you need, with the possible exception of it modifying `package-alist` (which you may or may not want to happen).  It's actually the call to `package-process-define-package` which does this.  If you wanted to avoid that modification, you could use:

```el
(let (package-alist)
  (package-load-descriptor DIRECTORY))
```